# Azure Databricks: Find Cloud Storage Location

Tags: azure-databricks, hive-metastore

I have a databricks workspace and want to find the storage location (**storage account name + container name**) where Databricks stores e.g. the table data.

I know that the default location is the storage account created when a databricks service is created. **Where can I see that storage location of DBFS Root?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each workspace has the `managedResourceGroupId` property that is resource ID of the managed resource group that holds a storage account. You need to look inside this resource group to find the created storage account, or also look into the `storageAccountName` parameter inside of the `parameters` section of Databricks workspace definition - it will give you an exact storage account name.  All of this could be done via ARM API if required.

But take into account that you can access data on DBFS root storage account only from the inside of the workspace - nobody can access that data except the Azure Databricks service.